# Retrieve data from external api with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

`I'm trying to retrieve some data from external api with laravel :
this is my controller

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

```
public function netvigie()  
    {
        $response = Http::get('https://extranet.netvigie.com/fr/api/{token}/availability/{id}/getAnomaliesCount?format=json');
        $data = json_decode($response->body(), true);
        dd($data);
        return view('ControlmAPI.netvigie');
    }

But i have curl error 28 while it works in Postman. We have only 2 parameters which are token and product id that we enter directly in the url.

Someone can help me please ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the complete error?

With Guzzle try:

```
$client->request('GET', 'example.com/example', ['connect_timeout' => 3.14]);//3.14 is seconds, try to increase it
```

if it still gives you problems try to increase

1. read_timeout
2. timeout

which are always request options of Guzzle

Comment: "cURL error 28: Failed to connect to extranet.netvigie.com port 443: Timed out " Ok i will try with guzzle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a timeout for your call?

```
Http::timeout(3)->get(...);
```

You can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#timeout

Comment: Hi, thank you.
I tried and increase the time but still the same error it's incomprehensible it works perfectly on Postman

Comment: Is the API required you to set the headers to application/json ? And you explicitly set the headers to application/json on Postman ? If it's yes, have you tried this

Http::asJson()->get(...)

Answer (score 0):

That's what i have when i try to dd :

```
public function netvigie()
       {
        return Http::dd()->get('https://extranet.netvigie.com/fr/api/{token}/availability/id/getStatusDetails?format=json');
       }
```

response :
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmLns.png)

It work with postman but with laravel i have "cURL error 28: Failed to connect to extranet.netvigie.com port 443: Timed out ". I tried to increase the time limit but it did not work.